# Summary Statistics with non-unique Case Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics, proximity

Is there an elegant way to run summary statistics and only keep a field if it matches the statistical test?

For example, I have some points, and distances from these points to several polygons. I run summary statistics to find the minimum distance for each point to the polygons, but I also want the name of the polygon it is closest to. Summary Statistics gives me the closest distance for each polygon, but I want to remove the polygons which are not closest.

Example below - take the pink squares, one is closer to the green polygon, others to the blue one.
[image]

Resulting summary stats give the following, with the closest distance to each polygon:
[image]

I just want to keep the closest one (0 metres in this example), but keep the polygon name.

I can just export to Excel and chuck it in a pivot table, but it would be nice to do this elegantly within ArcGIS.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to do (a picture may help) but I think you'll need to write a short ArcPy script or author a small model.

Comment: @PolyGeo updated now with an example. Yeah I was thinking I'd need to script it, but just in case there was a simple workaround.

Comment: Not sure I understand. But if min or max per some group field is what you want try Sort and Delete Identical. Or use arcpy (with pandas library). If you post some sample data I can show you an example, for example the attribute table as a csv file